# Is "You don't half sound confident" a positive or negative?

Tags: idioms-in-context

> "not half" means both of the positive and negative meaning.

You don't half sound confident.

https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/29b6a7873ba848088a44b99357af240a

How could we define the meaning as positive or negative?

Comment: note that "don't half sound" is an idiom. It is similar to **but different from** "not half".

Comment: @Fattie negative or positive idiom?

Comment: *"I don't know half of you half as well as I should like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.”*

Comment: @Mazura What does your sentence mean? Please rephrase.

Comment: @BEBYGONES If I say to you **"You don't half sound confident!"** it simply means "You sound very confident."  It's that simple. **There's absolutely nothing more to it. It's that simple.**  That could be a positive thing ("Great news! Beb is confident about the meeting!")  Or it could be I am implying you are arrogant, over-confident.

Comment: NOTE.  *You don't half sound confident* and *You don't sound half confident* are exactly the same.

Comment: Beb.  Note that the "half..." thing is very British.  Although, I would say, most Americans would get it from context.

Answer (score 6):

Oxford Languages gives as its first definition:

INFORMAL
not at all; in no way.
"the players are not half bad".

In this sense it means 'much less than half'.

The more common British usage is in the sense 'much more than half' - that is, very much so. "She wasn't half angry."

Comment: So how can you differentiate the postive and negative meaning?

Comment: Only by the context, I'm afraid.

Comment: @BEBYGONES *every single idiom* in English, can be either "positive" or "negative".  More generally, English is ***soaked*** in sarcasm and double-negatives.  It's completely normal that someone will say "of course", "sure", or "marvelous" and it has the exact opposite meaning.  It's completely pointless, unfortunately, ever asking if an idiom is "positive or negative".

Answer (score 2):

I think you can either take it as the semi-idiomatic phrase it is, that means they're good, or you can break it down somewhat logically and come to the same meaning anyway.

If something is "not half", it generally means less than 50%.

So, if something is less than half bad... It must be more than half good. It's essentially a double-negative.

So we get back to the original meaning that the thing is good.

It must be noted though that this is generally used to the effect of something that's very much to the positive as Kate points out in her answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly in this case it's a negative connotation.  Easiest way to determine that is to simplify the sentence.

Given:

"You don't half sound bad" means approximately: "You don't sound that bad"

We can do the same for 'confident':

"You don't half sound confident" means approximately: "You don't sound that confident"

In other words it's negative.

Comment: I disagree strongly. In some cases it will depend on the tone of voice, but as far as my imagination goes  _You don't half sound confident_ will **always** express being impressed at how supremely confident you sound.

Comment: This is wrong. The example sentence could very much be a good, or a bad, situation.

Comment: Colin, you don't have to disagree, because it's wrong :) :)   You can just state it's wrong.